# Chrome extension and mysql

Tags: mysql, google-chrome

I am trying to develop a chrome extension. 
Users have to send data to my server and receive data from my server.
I am new to chrome extension and I find the javascript cannot access the database. e.g MYSQL

I really don't know where to start?
I check the xmlhttprequest, but I still have no idea. Can anyone give me some more hints and suggestions?
If you can provide a sample code, this would be really helpful!

I am searching on the Internet for two days and totally get lost....
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create web-script with php, python, ruby etc

There you should provide a connection to mysql and process the data and print your result as JSON, for example.

Then you should get that json with ajax request by your chrome extension and process this json with your js code.